# How do I resolve json encode issue?

Tags: php

I have this code to convert a valid string into json.

```
$response = "{\"status\":\"success\",\"message\":\"Hosted Link\",\"data\":{\"link\":\"https:\/\/checkout-testing.herokuapp.com\/v3\/hosted\/pay\/9975b42eec3bfddf56c3\"}}";
$json = json_encode($response);
```

However when I do an echo to get the property like this:

```
echo $json->status;
```

I get below error:
'Illegal string offset 'status'

I even tried `json_encode($response, true);` , and tried getting status as an array, yet it returned with another error.

Can I get a suggestion on what could be wrong? And how I could fix this?

Comment: You want to use `json_decode()`, not `json_encode()`.

Comment: @Progman, have you tried json_decode? It doesn't work! Remember the goal here is to convert to string into json, and access it as an object by doing something like $json->status.   json_decode will not do it

Comment: @osagie have you tried `json_decode`? because that is exactly what it is for ... so apparenlty you didn't try it as I can decode your JSON string just fine with `json_decode`

Comment: @osagie Do you have a JSON string and want to convert it to an object/array/variable in PHP so you can access the data of the JSON string or do you have an object/array/variable in PHP (with all the data you have) and want to convert it to a JSON string?

Comment: @osagie The phrase "convert a string into JSON" does not make any sense. JSON is a way of representing data **as a string**, so what you have is already a string - a string which is in JSON format. What you want to do is convert a JSON string into something else - in this case, a **PHP object** or **PHP array**. And that, as others are telling you, is what `json_decode` is for.

Comment: @osagie Check the example on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3ba2bc512851494374f17db7543f297388907eaa and run it, you will see you get the output "success".

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I don't know what I was doing or thinking! Of course json_decode works.  Thanks

Comment: walk it off champ `;-)`

Comment: If you wanted to `encode` would need `$response = array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Hosted Link', 'data' => array('link' => 'https://checkout-testing.herokuapp.com/v3/hosted/pay/9975b42eec3bfddf56c3'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$json = json_decode($response);
```

Comment: it doesn't work. You can try this my particular example on an online compiler.

Comment: @osagie it works just fine

Comment: @lagbox & hamza, yes it works. Sorry for mixing stuffs up

Comment: no worries, good luck and have fun :)